# How to add users with username using mozilla-django-oidc to auth_user table upon SSO login?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm using `mozilla-django-oidc` for SSO login with one of my django application. When each user logs in to the application using SSO, then the user is added to the `auth_user` table of postgres database(if the user is not already saved).

The username column of the auth_user table is filled with the hash value of the email id. How can we save the actual value of the email id in the auth_user table instead of the hash value?

> A direction to achieve this is mentioned [here](https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#creating-django-users) in
> the official documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I did for connecting to Azure AADB2C, guess it's similar for keycloak, or other oidc providers..

###### 1.

Make sure your oidc provider supports `user_info` endpoint (which stored in `OIDC_OP_USER_ENDPOINT` settings value), otherwise the library fails to start (in case of azure aadb2c it means moving from `user flows` to `custom policies`, with corresponding customizations)

Then ping the endpoint (get or post) with `Authentification: Bearer ...` , and you'll see the field names needs mapping

```json
{
    "objectId": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "givenName": "Hello",
    "surname": "World",
    "displayName": "someuser",
    "signInNames.emailAddress": "someuser@example.com"
}
```

###### 2.

Override `mozilla_django_oidc.auth.OIDCAuthenticationBackend` methods which dealing with field names. the solution adopted from this guide
https://www.informaticsmatters.com/blog/2021/06/01/installing-keycloak-on-Django-rest-framework.html

settings.py

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'path.to.custom_backend.AADB2CAuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # keeping django 'native' users functionality
)
```

custom_backend.py

```py
# Classes to override default OIDCAuthenticationBackend (Keycloak authentication)
from mozilla_django_oidc.auth import OIDCAuthenticationBackend

class AADB2CAuthenticationBackend(OIDCAuthenticationBackend):

    def create_user(self, claims):
        """ Overrides Authentication Backend so that Django users are
            created with the keycloak preferred_username.
            If nothing found matching the email, then try the username.
        """
        user = super(ApiAuthenticationBackend, self).create_user(claims)
        user.first_name = claims.get('givenName', '')
        user.last_name = claims.get('surname', '')
        user.email = claims.get('signInNames.emailAddress')
        user.username = claims.get('displayName')
        user.save()
        return user

    def filter_users_by_claims(self, claims):
        """ Return all users matching the specified email.
            If nothing found matching the email, then try the username
        """
        email = claims.get('signInNames.emailAddress')
        preferred_username = claims.get('displayName')

        if not email:
            return self.UserModel.objects.none()
        users = self.UserModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)

        if len(users) < 1:
            if not preferred_username:
                return self.UserModel.objects.none()
            users = self.UserModel.objects.filter(username__iexact=preferred_username)
        return users

    def update_user(self, user, claims):
        user.first_name = claims.get('givenName', '')
        user.last_name = claims.get('surname', '')
        user.email = claims.get('signInNames.emailAddress')
        user.username = claims.get('displayName')
        user.save()
        return user

    #rbac adoptions
    #def verify_claims(self, claims):
    #    verified = super(AADB2CAuthenticationBackend, self).verify_claims(claims)
    #    #is_admin = 'admin' in claims.get('group', [])
    #    return verified #and is_admin
```

###### 3.

In case your're using DRF, I suffered unhandled exceptions on expired tokens, after discovering, it was the format of error message in `WWW-authenticate` header, so needed to update authentification class `mozilla_django_oidc.contrib.drf.OIDCAuthentication`  according to received values

settings.py

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        #'mozilla_django_oidc.contrib.drf.OIDCAuthentication',
        'path.to.custom_auth.AADB2CAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # other authentication classes, if needed
    ],
}
```

custom_auth.py

```py
from mozilla_django_oidc.contrib.drf import OIDCAuthentication
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured, SuspiciousOperation
from rest_framework import authentication, exceptions
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from mozilla_django_oidc.utils import import_from_settings, parse_www_authenticate_header



class AADB2CAuthentication(OIDCAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        """
        Authenticate the request and return a tuple of (user, token) or None
        if there was no authentication attempt.
        """
        access_token = self.get_access_token(request)

        if not access_token:
            return None

        try:
            user = self.backend.get_or_create_user(access_token, None, None)
        except HTTPError as exc:
            resp = exc.response

            # if the oidc provider returns 401, it means the token is invalid.
            # in that case, we want to return the upstream error message (which
            # we can get from the www-authentication header) in the response.
            if resp.status_code == 401 and 'www-authenticate' in resp.headers:
                data = parse_www_authenticate_header(resp.headers['www-authenticate'])
                if 'error_description' in data:
                    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(data['error_description'])
                #AADB2C customization
                elif 'Bearer error' in data:
                    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(data['Bearer error'])

            # for all other http errors, just re-raise the exception.
            raise
        except SuspiciousOperation as exc:
            #LOGGER.info('Login failed: %s', exc)
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Login failed')

        if not user:
            msg = 'Login failed: No user found for the given access token.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        return user, access_token
```