# Django/Flask : Rewritting an Flask Azure B2C authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, azure-ad-b2c

I want to use and Azure B2C authentication in Django, however there is no tutorial in Django for it but in Flask. However I never coded in Flask.

I used the documentation/tutorial of microsoft that share a github with the flask code to do it :

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=windows
2. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp

I try to convert it in Django however I have an error that I do not understand ! The error message :

```
Internal Server Error: /login/
TypeError: Object of type HttpResponseRedirect is not JSON serializable
```

Here is the code

##### views.py

```
def index(request) :
    if not request.session.get("user"):
        return redirect("login")
    return render('index.html', user=request.session["user"] )

def login(request):
    # Technically we could use empty list [] as scopes to do just sign in,
    # here we choose to also collect end user consent upfront
    request.session["flow"] = _build_auth_code_flow(scopes=list(json.loads(os.getenv("SCOPE"))))
  
    return render(request, "login.html", {'auth_url' : request.session["flow"]["auth_uri"]})


def authorized(request):
    try:
        cache = _load_cache(request=request)
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
            request.session.get("flow", {}), request.args)
        if "error" in result:
            return render("auth_error.html", result=result)
        request.session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache=cache, request=request)
    except ValueError:  # Usually caused by CSRF
        pass  # Simply ignore them
    return redirect("index")


def _load_cache(request):
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if request.session.get("token_cache"):
        cache.deserialize(request.ession["token_cache"])
    return cache

def _save_cache(cache, request):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        request.session["token_cache"] = cache.serialize()

def _build_msal_app(cache=None, authority=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        os.getenv("CLIENT_ID"), authority=authority or os.getenv("AUTHORITY"),
        client_credential=os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET"), token_cache=cache)

def _build_auth_code_flow(authority=None, scopes=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).initiate_auth_code_flow(
        scopes or [],
        redirect_uri=redirect('authorized'))
```

##### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Microsoft Identity Python Web App</h1>

    <li><a href='{{ auth_url }}'>Sign In</a></li>

    <footer style="text-align: right">Powered by MSAL Python {{ version }}</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

##### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name="index"),
    path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
    # path(f'{os.getenv("REDIRECT_PATH")}/', views.login, name="authorized"),
    path('getAToken/', views.login, name="authorized")
]
```

Did I do something wrond in the conversion to Django ?
Where does this error come from ? Is it something to set in the azure bc2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the required answer (adopting the Flask solution for DJango), but your're right, there are no examples of using Django for aadb2c auth...
What I did,  is used "mozilla-django-oidc" which fits well the azure oidc authentification..
More details are here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74156780/592737

Comment: I could manage to translate the Flask code to the Django. However, yes I do not find it satisfying